# How to hide App icon but keep Up button in Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, launcher

I am programming an application which using Slide Bar. I tried a sample from Google with Navigation Drawer.

Here is link download:

http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip
However I meet a problem. My application doesn't need Application Icon(ic_launcher.png) but keep Up button (ic_drawer.png).

I hide title by using: `getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` and `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`but It's doesn't hide App Icon.

Please help me solve this problem. This sample project doesn't have "style.xml" file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
actionbar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this works! Might want to qualify the R since it's not your App's R. ex: android.R.color.transparent